# How to do Pagination with All option in kendo grid with angular 2

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2

I want to add 'All' option pagination dropdown. How do I achieve this for Kendo Grid with Angular 2[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Grid PagerTemplate](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/data-operations/paging/#toc-pager-template) and provide a DropDownList (or other UI element of your preference) with custom page sizes and behavior, e.g.:

```
<ng-template kendoPagerTemplate let-totalPages="totalPages" let-currentPage="currentPage">
            <kendo-pager-prev-buttons></kendo-pager-prev-buttons>
            <kendo-pager-numeric-buttons [buttonCount]="10"></kendo-pager-numeric-buttons>
            <kendo-pager-info></kendo-pager-info>
            <kendo-pager-next-buttons></kendo-pager-next-buttons>
            <kendo-dropdownlist 
              [data]="pageSizes"
              [textField]="'text'"
              [valueField]="'value'"
              [valuePrimitive]="true"
              [(value)]="pageSize"></kendo-dropdownlist>
         </ng-template>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/WhSEx43QOcaGWc8cgdDc?p=preview)